# How to use opusdec to convert .flac's to .opus recursively, whilst maintaining directory structure in the destination folder?

Tags: convert, flac, ogg-opus

Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/keeferrourke/13613bfaae34c0d7528f12ea5d7cafc5) but with those two functionalities, please.

Comment: What have you tried so far please, and at which step are you having difficulty?

Comment: @TomBrossman  I did make some changes to the script on my end so that it doesn't delete embeded cover art which is nice, but has nothing to do with my problem. 

Kay Urbach's answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114908/bash-script-to-convert-all-flac-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg) looks promising but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: @TomBrossman I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question by adding 'flac2opus' lines [84 to 88](https://gist.github.com/keeferrourke/13613bfaae34c0d7528f12ea5d7cafc5) (excluding the '--discard-comments' flag in my case) to line 49 of [this](https://github.com/erdnuesse/flac-to-mp3/blob/master/transform.sh) script, taking 'avconv''s place.

Looking like this:

```
opusenc --vbr --bitrate ??? --music --date "$DATE" \
--title "$TITLE" --artist "$ARTIST" --album "$ALBUM" --genre "$GENRE" \
--comment "ALBUMARTIST=$ALBUMARTIST" --comment "DISCNUMBER=$DISCNUMBER" \
--comment "TRACKNUMBER=$TRACKNUMBER" --comment "TRACKTOTAL=$TRACKTOTAL" \
--comment "LYRICS=$LYRICS" "$fullfile" "$outfile"
```

Make sure to keep **"$fullfile"** and **"$outfile"** at the end. Edit script paths to match your own.

**EDIT** I ran the 'transform.sh' independently.